# (Mono) How to get the MonoClass* of the class within another class?

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I have a class within another class in the C# script, such as

```
namespace N{
  public class A{
    private class B{}
  }
}
```

Then I tried to get the assembly classes in Mono. When class B is retrieved, the following results will occur.

```
const MonoTableInfo* tableInfo = mono_image_get_table_info( image, MONO_TABLE_TYPEDEF );
uint32_t rows = mono_table_info_get_rows( tableInfo );

for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
  uint32_t cols[ MONO_TYPEDEF_SIZE ];
  mono_metadata_decode_row( tableInfo, i, cols, MONO_TYPEDEF_SIZE );
  const char* name = mono_metadata_string_heap( image, cols[ MONO_TYPEDEF_NAME ] ); // "B"
  const char* nameSpace = mono_metadata_string_heap( image, cols[ MONO_TYPEDEF_NAMESPACE ] ); // ""
  MonoClass* klass = mono_class_from_name( image, nameSpace, name ); // nullptr
}
```

After that, I tried to use mono_class_from_name definitely, but it does not work.

```
  MonoClass* klass1 = mono_class_from_name( image, "",  "A.B" ); // nullptr
  MonoClass* klass2 = mono_class_from_name( image, "N", "B"   ); // nullptr
  MonoClass* klass3 = mono_class_from_name( image, "N", "A.B" ); // nullptr
```

So how could I get the MonoClass* of the class within another class?

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: *"I have a class within another class"*. Probably a bad idea in the first place. It should rarely be done unless the inner class is private. Microsoft used to do it a bit, e.g. `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem`, but they tend to avoid that now too.

Comment: @John The inner class in my project is actually private. ```private class Enumerator : IEnumerator```. My topic of this question is Mono, but I edited it. So thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

We need to format the name like this: MyNamespace.MyParentClass/MyNestedClass.

```
MonoClass* klass = mono_class_from_name( image, "N",  "A/B" ); // it works
```

The namespaces and parent classes of nested classes are not available through `mono_metadata_string_heap`. And We need a better and more reasonable way to separate the non-nested classes and nested classes here.